# Debugging asynchronous iOS code in a run loop?

Tags: objective-c, ios, debugging, asynchronous

I have a program that does a lot of asynchronous web interaction using an NSRunLoop. I've got a " message sent to deallocated instance" error right now, but because the program is asynchronous, I don't know anything about where the error happened because I don't get a stack trace.

Are there any tips or tools that would be helpful in fixing this problem? I could throw in lots of debugging statements, but that doesn't seem like the right answer.

Comment: If you're using XCode, you could run the static analyzer on your code and see if it uncovers any errors.

Comment: You can see the stack traces for each active thread on the debugger view.

Comment: I'm using NSInvocation to call some of the methods though, so I'm only  shown the NSRunLoop starting call in the debugger view, unfortunately. I'm looking through the analyzer, thanks! Also, Zombies?

Comment: build for simulator -> profile (instruments) -> zombies